# What does index do in react-navigation state

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I was going through [React-navigation reset actions from their docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/)

Where they have shared snippet example which looks like this

```
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    index: 1,
    routes: [
      { name: 'Home' },
      {
        name: 'Profile',
        params: { user: 'jane' },
      },
    ],
  })
);
```

From her I wasn't able to figure out what does index do?

I went through state object for [react-navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-state) where they have written this

```
index - Index of the focused route object in the routes array
```

So I went through their example on [expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/BtsAT7ykT)

and changed reset function to this

```
 <Button
    title="Reset navigation state"
    onPress={() =>
      navigation.dispatch(
        CommonActions.reset({
          index: 0,
          routes: [
            {
              name: 'Profile',
              params: { user: 'Cyberduck', key: route.params.key },
            },
            { name: 'Home' },
          ],
        })
      )
    }
  />
```

In the above I have changed index to 0 and  `params: { user:` to `'Cyberduck'`. I was hoping when I click on this it will change the name from  jane to Cyberduck but instead it navigated me to `Home` screen even though my index is 0 and the first object in my routes array is Profile screen.

If I remove `{ name: 'Home' },` object then it changes the name from Jane to Cyberduck

Can someone explain me index in react-navigation?

Answer (score 0):

.reset() method is reset your route and index is like where to put your new route

like an array if you have array then you need  to your item in particular place so you use arrayName[index] so in here you are using reset() method to it will reset you stack with this index and only one route at that index above all route was delete  ex. you put your route on 0 index then all pervious stack are deleted and you stack recreate with 0.

if you don't wanna this then use jumpTo()

ignore my spell and grammar mistake
hope this may help.